# IF Inside WHERE with stored procedure

Tags: sql, if-statement, null, where-clause

I have a WHERE statement that looks like this:

```
WHERE 
    ((@Value1 IS NULL AND [value1_id] IS NULL) OR [value1_id] = ISNULL(@Value1, [value1_id]))
    AND
    ((@Value2 IS NULL AND [value2_id] IS NULL) OR [value2_id] = ISNULL(@Value2, [value2_id]))
    AND
    ((@Value3 IS NULL AND [value3_id] IS NULL) OR [value3_id] = ISNULL(@Value3, [value3_id]))
    AND
    ((@Value4 IS NULL AND [value4_id] IS NULL) OR [value4_id] = ISNULL(@Value4, [value4_id]))
    AND
    ((@Value5 IS NULL AND [value5_id] IS NULL) OR [value5_id] = ISNULL(@Value5, [value5_id]))
    AND 
    ((@Value6 IS NULL AND [value6_id] IS NULL) OR [value6_id] = ISNULL(@Value5, [value6_id]))
```

I need to add some conditional logic inside of the WHERE so I can do special things with Value5 and Value6. Basically, if Value5, Value6, or another value is null, I want to use the Value 5 and Value 6 lines as is. If all three values aren't NULL, I need to run some calculations on the values.

Any ideas on what the best action would be?

Comment: You know the last line is different?  It has a "@Value5" mixed in there:  [value6_id] = ISNULL(@Value5, [value6_id]))

Comment: @criticalfix Thanks, but it's irrelevant. I replaced the real names with dummy names.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem yet?

Answer (score 4):

Use CASE

"CASE can be used in any statement or clause that allows a valid expression. For example, you can use CASE in statements such as SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE and SET, and in clauses such as select_list, IN, WHERE, ORDER BY, and HAVING."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

You can perform calculations inside of a `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @Value7 is not null THEN @Value7 * 100
        ELSE Value7 * 100
    END
FROM #T
WHERE   (@Value1 is null and Value1 is null)
    AND (@Value2 is null and Value2 is null)
```

It's still not very clear what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Is the `WHERE` not inside a `SELECT`? Provide a clear, concise example if the above is not correct.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I attempted this, but SQL is having none of it. The IDE is only showing CAST when I start typing and gives an error if CASE is in there. I think it has something to do with the combination of CASE with AND.

Comment: Do you have a simplified example for us to work with? I assumed you were on SQL Server... What are you using? Pseudocode an example will work

Comment: I would try more with CASE, or post the code with CASE that gives the error.

Comment: @J Lo I am using SQL Server. My understanding of CASE is obviously off. It seems most examples I'm seeing, are trying to assign a value with WHERE and CASE. Where I am just trying to execute two different pieces of code. http://pastebin.com/caLukCuy That is what I'm essentially trying to accomplish. It's obviously not correct, I just wrote it out real quick in Notepad so you can get an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, if Value5, Value6, or another value is null, I want to use
>   the Value 5 and Value 6 lines as is. If all three values aren't NULL,
>   I need to run some calculations on the values.

I think this will be hard to do with for example a `CASE` inside the `WHERE` clause. You might be better off with an `IF` construction outside of your `SELECT` statements:

```
IF (@Value5 IS NULL OR @Value6 IS NULL OR @OtherValue IS NULL)
  BEGIN
    <Statement1AsIs>
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    <Statement2WithComputations>
  END
```

**Rewrite WHERE clause**

On a short sidenote, I know you did not ask for it, but I have the feeling there must be a 'clearer' way to write these

```
((@Value1 IS NULL AND [value1_id] IS NULL) OR [value1_id] = ISNULL(@Value1, [value1_id]))
```

I've been playing around a bit and this is one way to say the same:

```
COALESCE(@Value1, [value1_id], 1001) = COALESCE([value1_id], 1001)
```

This is another one, equivalent and shorter:

```
@Value1 IS NULL OR [value1_id] = ISNULL(@Value1, [value1_id])
```

Check out this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06381/1)** to see the equivalence.